# Depth First Search to find all paths between nodes issue

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I have been trying to fix this Depth First Search problem but I cant figure it out. I want to print all paths but somehow it only prints some paths. I can figure out the mistake here for such a long time:

```
  void printAllPathsUtil(Vertex v, Vertex d, ArrayList<Vertex> path){

        v.state = VISITED;
        path.add(v);

        if (v == d) {
            for (Vertex p : path) {
                System.out.print("Print: " + p.value + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        else {
            for (Vertex city : v.outboundCity){

                if (city.state == UNVISITED) {

                    printAllPathsUtil(city, d, path);
                }
            }
        }
        path.remove(v);
        v.state = UNVISITED;
    }


    void printAllPaths(Vertex v, Vertex u){
        clearStates();
        ArrayList<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<>();
        printAllPathsUtil(v, u, path);
    }
```

Vertex Class is something like this:

```
public class Vertex{
String value;

Vertex previous = null;
int minDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

List<Vertex> inboundCity;
List<Vertex> outboundCity;
State state;
}
```

Comment: Post your ``Vertex`` class please

Comment: @Schidu Luca Done

Comment: The part above looks correct.  Your error must be somewhere else, I think.  Maybe you initialized your graph incorrectly?

Comment: is this a cycle free graph? else you would run into problems when you remove already visited nodes

Comment: Graph can have cycles

Comment: @orange14 - I verified your test case, everything works correctly, it displays all the path ...

Comment: I agree with you but it does not show all cyclic cases. In my example, in the gihub, there is a cycle and it does not display that.

Comment: What cycles are not diplayed? And why do you want to display cycles? Let's assume we have the following routes: AB, BC, BD, CE, DE, EF and we want the routes from A to F. Then we get the following: ABCEF and ABDEF, I think displaying ABCEDBCEF would be unnecessary. It is the existing ABCEF route with an extra circle. If you want to display all of these extra circles then there will be infinite solutions if there is at least one cycle in your graph.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have this two lines inside the `loop`:

```
path.remove(v);
v.state = UNVISITED;
```

You should remove vertexes from path and "unvisit" them right after your recursion is terminated, not when you end the loop

Comment: so you mean path.remove(v);  v.state = UNVISITED; should be moved inside else statement

Comment: Yes, even inside that ``loop`` of yours

Comment: right after the ``printAllPathsUtil(city, d, path);``

Comment: These changes only print one path only A, B, C

Comment: @orange14 Can you post an example,  how you know it only prints some paths? maybe ur algorithm is running correctly

Comment: Yes lemme send you link to example. 1 min

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152752/discussion-between-orange14-and-schidu-luca).

Comment: I pushed my code to github here: https://github.com/aamalik/railroadservice

Comment: I think this is a bad idea